# How to open a QGIS Project with Optionspath and Configpath settings?

Tags: qgis, qgs

Is there a way of forcing QGIS to use the network settings for the Optionspath and Configpath switches (which i have added to the target for the QGIS desktop icon on my pc) when opening a Project that is also on the desktop?

At the moment, if I open the QGIS desktop icon, everything opens as i have configured it, looking at the network location (with all the plugins we are using there as well as the customisation); Opening the project icon results in QGIS not adhering to these settings.

I have tweaked the QGIS bat file in the Program Files location as this;

```
@echo off

call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%

set QGIS_CONFIGPATH="\\gis\GIS\Qgis\Customisations\Hsg"

set QGIS_OPTIONSPATH="\\gis\GIS\Qgis\Customisations\Hsg" 

set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis

set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE

set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000

set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt4\plugins

start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-bin.exe %*
```

but it still doesn't appear to work properly

Has anyone got any ideas?